# Funtional way to find empty intervals in a list of tuples with start and end times

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Say I have a list of tuples with start and end times:

```
List((1,10), (2,11), (3,11), (13,14))
```

The only relaxation is that start times are ascending

I expect the following output:

```
List((0,1), (11,13))
```

The procedural implementation is fairly straightforward, however I wouldn't have a clue to do this (idiomatically) functional.

A scala-for-yield loop seems to be a bad fit, since the result would be of the same size as the input. Whereas a reduce/fold would restrict me to have only one tuple as the answer.

Comment: Are you only working with integers ? Or at least with a discrete set of values ?

Comment: In the actual problem yes, they're unix timestamps.

Comment: are you looking for a library or a description of an algorithm? This might be relevant: https://github.com/rklaehn/intervalset

Comment: You could get the minimum of the begin time and the maximum of the end times, generate a list of all the integers between those two values. Then map on your list and "erase" the value in the generated list for each interval. What would be left will be all the values you need. Then you just have to regroup the consecutives values of it to get your desired output.

Comment: @meucaa, although that might seem a viable solution with the numbers used in the example, using this in my case with a List of values spanning sparse numbers, would be extremely wasteful, resource-wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following solution:

```
list
  .foldLeft((List[(Int,Int)](), 0)) {
     case ((res, se), (s, e)) => 
       if(s>se) ((se, s)::res,e) 
       else (res, e)
  }
  ._1
  .reverse
```

Explanation. We accumulate pair of values: List of empty intervals (which is initially empty, List(Int, Int)) and end of last interval (initially 0). On each step take current interval (s, e) and compare it with end of last interval. If start of current interval greater than end of last then there is a gap and we take it to result: `(se, s)::res`

Comment: I underestimated the possibilities with folding. This is beautiful, though resembles my procedural solution, so maybe I wasn't so far off after all.

Comment: Btw, you could add just a little condition to handle the case is se > e (you keep the last end interval) 

`if(s>se) ((se, s)::res,e) 
     else (e>se) (res,e)
     else (res, se)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of scanLeft a filter and a map

```
list.scanLeft((0,0,0))((l,r) => 
  if(r._1 > l._3) {(l._2, r._1, r._2)} 
  else {(l._1,r._2, r._2)}) 
filter(x => x._2 != x._3) 
map(x => (x._1, x._2))
```

During the scan we look at the right-hand element of the scan-pair, i.e. a job, to see if it is larger than the end-time so far (initiated with the (0,0,0) triplet). If so, we output a triplet containing, in order,

1. The start of the gap
2. The end of the gap
3. The stop time of the job that ended the gap.

If the right-hand's, i.e. job's, start time is not larger than the left-hand's end time, there is no empty gap and we create a triplet which enlarges the current job-streak (by lack of a better term), by

1. copy  the job-streak's start time
2. copy the last job's end-time
3. same as 2.

We can now identify gaps by seeing that the second and third element of the triplets differ (verify this is a iff-relation). We now filter on this fact. Finally we map so we get the appropriate output form.